# How to pass the list of integers inside count in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have IQueryable query with filters.

```
 IQueryable<User> usersQuery = Context.Users;
```

I need to pass list of integers instead of single integer value.

```
usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.UsersHRs.Count(um => um.Id == 1233 ) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
var ints = new []{1,2,3}; // somehow fill ints
usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.UsersHRs.Where(um => ints.Contains(um.Id)).Count() > 0);
```

Comment: @HarishBatchu If answer works for you please mark it as accepted (the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

update your query to

```
var ListOfIds = //list of integers
usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.UsersHRs.Count(um => ListOfIds.Contains(um.Id)) > 0);
```

Comment: @HarishBatchu, thanks, you could upvote it or mark either Guru's answer and mine